# Add up the number of consecutive True/False in DolphinDB

Tags: addition, dolphindb

As shown in the picture, the first 4 values are false and the cum value is 4. Then the fifth value is true, return 0. How to add up the number of consecutive false values?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`cumPositiveStreak` can add up the number of consecutive **true** values in a boolean vector.